# Create a viewpager image gallery in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

I am creating a simple viewpager image gallery, there is a viewpager and each page has a touch image view which can zoom and panning the image.

I have successfully display image on it. The problem is , when I swap the picture the zoom level is retain . E.g. When I zoom in first page, I try to swap to second page, then return to first page, and the zoom level does not return to default.

```
private class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return show_list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_zoom_item, container, false);

        final TouchImageView imageView = (TouchImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);

        if (show_list.get(position).contains("http://")) {
            ImageRequest ir = new ImageRequest(show_list.get(position),
                    new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(response);
                            imageView.resetZoom();
                        }
                    }, 0, 0, null, null);
            gs.addToRequestQueue(ir, "get_img");
        }

        container.addView(itemView);
        return itemView;
    }



    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }
}
```

The touch image view itself has the function to reset zoom level, the only problem is how to get the state "when the page change" and get the view of that page?

Thanks

Comment: try to reset zoom inside `onPageSelected`

Comment: thanks , one more problem is how to get the view inside instantiateItem?

Answer (score 0):

```
pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener(){

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    View rootview = pager.findViewWithTag(pager.getCurrentItem());
                    TouchImageView imageView = (TouchImageView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.img);
                    imageView.resetZoom();
                }

            });
```

And

```
private class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return show_list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_zoom_item, container, false);

        final TouchImageView imageView = (TouchImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);

        if (show_list.get(position).contains("http://")) {
            ImageRequest ir = new ImageRequest(show_list.get(position),
                    new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(response);
                        }
                    }, 0, 0, null, null);
            gs.addToRequestQueue(ir, "get_img");
        }

        itemView.setTag(position);
        container.addView(itemView);
        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }
}
```

just notice need to use set tag to get the view at the onPageSelected, thanks for ρяσѕρєя K help.